# Why i'm having this javascript exception on select2: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I'm in a project that uses AngularJS v1.2.10 (and Java, Spring MVC, JPA, etc.). We have some Select2 selectors that are working fine but sometimes javascript console oputputs the following error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of null
  clazz.opened @ select2.js?rld=1.2.0-B2:1187 
  (anonymous function) @ select2.js?rld=1.2.0-B2:1401
  n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js?rld=1.2.0-B2:3
  n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js?rld=1.2.0-B2:3
```

As an example, one of our Select2 declarations are:

```
  ## Municipality
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="municipalitySelector">#springMessageText('Address.municipality')</label>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="municipality" id="municipalitySelector" ui-select2="editCtrl.optionsSelectMunicipality" ng-model="center.address.municipality" required/>
       <cd-validation field="center.address.municipality" name="municipality" required="true" form="procedureForm" ctrl="editCtrl"></cd-validation>
     </div>
   </div>
```

As i say everything is working fine but this exceptions are anoying. When they apear first (after using the Selector) they are triggered even with the page scroll event so lots of exceptions are printed in the console.

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using?

Comment: We are using Select2 with AngularJS v1.2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are trying to access them before they are build on the page? That's a usual case. Maybe the code that calls should be wrapped in an "onload" callback.

Comment: No, the page is completely loaded. It happens when scrolling after using the  the selector. It's very strange.

Comment: Is there a way to see it working somewhere? Maybe we can debug the callstack together.